# Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history in some of git-svn commands

Tags: git, git-svn

I have a problem with `git svn`

For this one, it occurs when try to `git svn dcommit`

```
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history.
Perhaps the repository is empty. at C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 780.
```

I also have a problem with `git svn info` which show the same error message.

I try many ways as another topic provided but it never work. :(

I already try `git fsck`, `git svn rebase -l` also.

My repository is about 20,000 revisions. I fetched from http://localhost which sync from the original url, and after that, I change the url to the original one (in .git/config), after change I can run `git svn fetch` without problem. after that I follow [this blog](http://theadmin.org/articles/git-svn-switch-to-a-different-a-svn-url/).

The problem still occurs.

Comment: So http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269566/unable-to-determine-upstream-svn-information-from-head-history didn't help?

Comment: No. not help. I use both git and subversion with final version. TortoiseGit 1.7.4.0 , git version 1.7.7.1.msysgit.0, TortoiseSVN 1.7.1, Build 22161 - 64 Bit , 2011/10/21 22:51:59
Subversion 1.7.1,

Comment: It would be interesting to check if SVN1.7+ is supported with Git, or, if you can, whether a downgrade to SVN1.6+ wouldn't give better results.

Comment: From what I know there are multiple possible causes that may result in this error message, inclusive of existing bugs in `git svn`. In your case the irregular procedure of fetching from localhost might be the culprit, since there might be portions of the configuration that is still pointing back to the localhost address

Comment: The procedure from the blog-entry worked for me (SVN 1.6, git 1.8). Saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

I've this use cause.

I have my project on Git **marcusproject**.

For some policies I have to manage SVN and Git toghether so I decided to use git svn.

Git svn works starting from SVN and for me It's a problem because I come from a git project.

So

- Starting from Git I committed my project to **my_svn_repo_url**
- Then in a new folder I run:

  git svn clone **my_svn_repo_url**
  (Note: After git svn clone you have to add again the remote)

  git remote add origin git@myurlgitrepo:/path/git/marcusproject.git

Now if I run

```
git svn info
```

all works fine.

```
    marco$ git svn info 

Path: 
 URL: http://myurl/svn/url/branches/project Repository 

Root: blablabla Repository UUID: 2e790b0d-f755-41c8-864a-d7ceaa3670a7 

Revision: 36 

Node Kind: directory Schedule: normal

 Last Changed Author: author 

Last Changed Rev: 36 

Last Changed Date: 2015-04-16 12:54:19 +0200 (Gio, 16 Apr 2015)
```

If I switch to a git branch already exists 
run git pull origin mybranch
and the run git svn info i receive this error

```
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history.
Perhaps the repository is empty.
```

But if I create my new branch starting from the new master
git checkout -b newbranch
all works fine.

So :

1. push all your commit on git
2. migrate to git svn (git svn clone)
3. forget all your branches created before the "git svn clone"
4. create new branch starting from new master

You will never see that error.

Enjoy